# Subobject collection as columns in a variable columns table

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a db that represents rebilling information.
Company A receives an invoice and splits it to companies A, B, C.

For each incoming invoice we need to create a rebilling document.

The db I created has the following specs:

- Document has an ID other info (description, invoice date, ...)
- It has a variable number of rows, one for each of the original invoice rows.
- It has a variable number of columns, for companies the invoice will be split to.
- Each row in the same document has the same number of column.

This is a stripped representation of the db:

```
+-----------------+   +------------------+   +--------------------+
| DOCUMENTS       +   | ROWS             |   | COLS               |
+-----------------+   +------------------+   +--------------------+
| DocID        PK |1-*| DocID         PK |1-*| DocID           PK |   +-----------------+
| ...             |   | Row           PK |1-*| Row             PK |   | COMPANIES       |
+-----------------+   | Description      |   | Col             PK |   +-----------------+ 
                      | RebillAmount     |   | CompanyID          |*-1| CompanyID    PK |
                      +------------------+   | RebilledAmount     |   | Description     |
                                             +--------------------+   +-----------------+
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a grid representation, like this:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Description     | RebillAmount | "Company A" | "Company B" | "Company C" | ...
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ISP invoice     |   € 1.000,00 |    € 333,00 |    € 333,00 |    € 334,00 |
| Insurance       |     € 600,00 |      € 0,00 |    € 400,00 |    € 200,00 | 
| ...             |              |             |             |             |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Data are retrieved using Linq to SQL.

I succesfully created a DataGridView by manually iterating through rows and cols, using a dictionary to keep track of columns:

```
Dim CompanyCols as new Dictionary(Of Integer, DataGridViewColumn)

Dim DocID = 1
Dim Doc = (From d In dc.Documents Where f.DocID = DocID Select d).Single

For Each r In Doc.Rows
    Dim rowid = Grid.Rows.Add()
    Dim row = Grid.Rows(rowid)
    row.Cells(ColEnum.Description).Value = r.Description
    riga.Cells(ColEnum.RebillAmount).Value = r.RebillAmount
    Dim col As DataGridViewColumn
    For Each c In r.Cols
        If CompanyCols.ContainsKey(c.CompanyID) Then
            col = CompanyCols(c.CompanyID)
        Else
            Dim newcol = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.HeaderText = c.Companies.Description}
            col = Grid.Columns(Grid.Columns.Add(newcol))
            CompanyCols.Add(c.CompanyID, col)
        End If
        row.Cells(col.Index).Value = c.RebillAmount
    Next
Next
```

Unfortunately, this approach breaks the link with database objects, so if I need to edit data and save them I have to scan the whole grid and manually update "Doc" object and its sub-objects.

Is there a way to "bind" rows to Doc.rows and columns to Doc.cols?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a collection of Documents. You want to display one Document in a table. The columns in the table represent the `Companies` that are mentioned in the Document. Different Documents may have different number of companies.

Luckily you only want to display only one Document in your table: once you've got a Document you know which Companies should be added as columns to your table.

Although you defined that in one Document every row has the **same number of Columns**, and thus that every Document uses the same number of Companies, you didn't specify that every Row uses the same Companies.

So you could end up with this:

```
Rows[0] has two Cols:
    Cols[0] has Company[0]
    Cols[1] has Company[1]
Rows[1] has two Cols:
    Cols[0] has Company[0]
    Cols[1] has Company[2]
Rows[3] has two Cols:
    Cols[0] has Company[3]
    Cols[1] has Company[4]
```

If I look at your code, in this case you want to show 5 columns.

```
Row        Company[0]   Company[1]  Company[2]   Company[3]  Company[4]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Row[0]       aaa           bbb
Row[1]       ccc                       ddd
Row[2]                                               eee         fff
```

Every company column in your table has a column header that shows the name of the company. If you have a row, the value of the cells of the row are either null if the company is not used by the row, or the `RebilledAmount` of the cell that uses the company whose name is shown in the column header.

This means that once you've fetched your document, you'll need to know all used Companies. Every Company becomes one Column. With every Column you'll need to remember the name of the Company and the Id of the Company

For every Row you want to add, you'll have to find out the column that matches the Ids of the Companies that are used by the Cols of this Row.

My visual basic is a little bit rusty, so I'll show you the code in C#. I'm sure you'll be able to grasp the idea and translate it to visual basic

```
Document fetchedDocument = ...

// find out which companies are used by the Document.
// from every company remember the name and the Id:
var companyInfo = fetchedDocument.Rows      // take all rows
    .SelectMany(row => row.Cols)            // from these rows take all Cols
    .Select(col => new
    {
         CompanyId = col.CompanyId,         // from every Col take the CompanyId
         Name = col.Company.Name,           // and the company name
    })  
    .Distinct();                            // remove duplicates
```

If you didn't fetch the CompanyNames when you fetched the Document, you'll have to fetch them in a separate query. If you have the company names somewhere locally, in a Dictionary or something fetch them by afterwards:

```
var companyIds = fetchedDocument.Rows        // take all rows
    .SelectMany(row => row.Cols)             // from all rows take the Cols
    .Select(col => col.CompanyId)            // from every col take the companyId
    .Distinct();                             // remove duplicates

// add the CompanyNames
var companyInfo = companyIds.Select(companyId => new
{
    Id = companyId,
    Name = CompanyCollection[companyId].CompanyName,
});
```

Once you know all companies you can add all columns. We'll first add the columns for the `Description` and the `RebillAmount`:

```
myDataGridView.Columns.Clear();

// Column Description:
int columnDescriptionIndex = myDataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn()
{
    Name = "ColDescription",             // name of the column
    HeaderText = "Description",          // header text
    ValueType = typeof(string),          // this column shows strings
    DataPropertyName = "Description",    // this column shows property Description
});

// Column RebillAmount:
int columnRebillAmountIndex = myDataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn()
{
    Name = "ColRebillAmount",             // name of the column
    HeaderText = "RebillAmount",          // header text
    DataPropertyName = "RebillAmount",    // this column shows property RebillAmount
    ValueType = typeof(decimal),          // this column shows decimals
    // if desired: add a DefaultCellStyle to define the display format of the amount
}
```

Now add the company columns. With each company column you'll need to remember the Id of the company being shown. For this we create a SubClass of DataGridViewColumn that contains the Id of the company being shown:

```
class CompanyColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public int CompanyId {get; private set;}

    public CompanyColumn(int companyId, string companyName)
    {
        this.CompanyId = companyId;
        Name = companyName;               // name of the column
        HeaderText = companyName;         // header text
        ValueType = typeof(decimal);      // this column shows decimals
        // if desired: add a DefaultCellStyle to define the display format
    }
}
```

Add one column per used company; for fast lookup: put the column index in a Dictionary,
with key is companyId and value is columnIndex

```
var companyColumns = new Dictionary<int, int>()
foreach(var usedCompany in usedCompanies)
{
     var columnIndex = myDataGridView.Columns
         .Add(new CompanyColumn(usedCompany.Id, usedCompany.Name);
     companyColumns.Add(usedCompany.Id, columnIndex);
}
```

After you've added all columns, you can add the rows:

```
myDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

foreach(var row in document.Rows)
{
    var addedRow = myDataGridView.AddRow();

    // Description and RebillAmount
    addedRow.Cells[colDescriptionIndex].Value = row.Description;
    addedRow.Cells[colRebillAmountIndex].Value = row.RebillAmount;

    // add the value for every company in the row, in the correct column
    foreach (var col in row.Cols
    {
        // every col has a companyId
        // find in the dictionary the index of the column that represents this company
        int columnIndex = companyColumns[col.CompanyId];

        // put the RebilledAmount in the column with the found index
        addedRow.Cells[columnIndex].Value = cell.RebilledAmount;
    }
}
```

Now if a cell is changed, you want to change the corresponding value in Documents:

```
void UpdateChangedCell(DataGridViewCell cell)
{
     if (cell.ColumnIndex == colDescriptionIndex)
     {    // the changed cell is a description cell
          string description = (string)cell.Value;
          document.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Description = description;
     }
     else if (cell.ColumnIndex == colRebillAmountIndex)
     {    // the changed cell is a rebillAmount cell
          decimal rebillAmount = (decimal)cell.Value;
          document.Rows[cell.RowIndex].RebillAmount = rebillAmount;
     }
     else
     {   // the changed cell is in one of the company columns:
         CompanyColumn column = (CompanyColumn)myDataGridView.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex];
          int companyId = column.CompanyId;
          decimal rebilledAmount = (decimal)column.Value;

          // update the one and only Col in this Row that has CompanyId
          var colToUpdate = row.Cols
              .Where(col => col.CompanyId == companyId)
              .Single();
          colToUpdate.RebilledAmount = rebilledAmount;
     }
}
```